# option data:{dateFormat:'dd/mm/YYY'} does not work properly

Tags: highcharts

When working with data from `csv` option `data:{dateFormat:'dd/mm/YYY'}` does not work. Always uses `dateFormat:'mm/dd/YYYY'`. is there anyway to make it work without converting the all `datetime` column in `.csv` file?

Comment: You specifically want `YYY` rather than `YY` or `YYYY`?

Comment: Hello. Sorry, I meant 'dd/mm/YYYY'. Although 'options.data.dataFormat' is configured with this type of dataFormat, HighStock does not seem to obey and takes 'month' firstly and then 'day of month'. So when Highstocks receives '03/01/2015' it is interpreted as  March first of 2015 when it really means January third of 2015.

Comment: How you parse your data? X values (dates) are timestamps ? Could you supply piece of code, ?